# How has FAR 61.57 changed since 1969?

Tags: far-61

[An answer to another question on Aviation.SE asks about the historical development of FAR 61.57.](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/3398/167)

**How has FAR 61.57 changed over the years?**

Answer (score 4):

### Glad you asked!

I referenced historical FARs from **2013**, **1993**, **1988**, and **1969**.  Here's what I found:

[image: 2013-1]
[image: 2013-2]
[image: 1993-1]
[image: 1993-2]
[image: 1988-1]
[image: 1988-2]
[image: 1969]

Answer (score 3):

Why yes, it has, and the history along with the preambles and lots of other good information is available on the FAA's Regulatory Guidance Library.

Click the image and then click on Historical CFR and then By Part and follow the tree to 61.57 to see the history:

[image: RGL History]

More details are available here:  [How can I see the revision history of a particular FAR?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/427/how-can-i-see-the-revision-history-of-a-particular-far)

Comment: Huh.  That would have saved me some gas.  Curses.